# Function based off of form input selec?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Issue:** My form passes/POSTS the last selection available instead of the one chosen.

I have a form which dynamically hides or shows based on selection of the following:

```
<select id="country" class="form-control form-group">
    <option value="nil">-- select one -- </option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="AU">Australia</option>
    <option value="AT">Austria</option>
    <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
    <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
...
```

Now, what appears based on that selection is the following and where my issue comes:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :address_state, "State/Province/Region" %>
<div id="us-states">
     <%= f.select(:address_state, options_for_select((us_states), @stripe_account[:address_state]), {}, { class: "form-control input-lg"}) %>
</div>
<div id="au-regions"  style="display:none;" <%= 'hidden' unless @stripe_account.country == "US" %> >
     <%= f.select(:address_state, options_for_select((au_regions), @stripe_account[:address_state]), {}, { class: "form-control input-lg", id: "address_state au_regions"}) %>
</div>
<div id="at-states" style="display:none;">
     <%= f.select(:address_state, options_for_select((at_states), @stripe_account[:address_state]), {}, { class: "form-control input-lg", id: "address_state at_states"}) %>
</div>
...
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>

$("#country").on("change",function(){"US"===$(this).val()?$("#us-states").show():$("#us-states").hide()});
$("#country").on("change",function(){"AU"===$(this).val()?$("#au-regions").show():$("#au-regions").hide()});
$("#country").on("change",function(){"AT"===$(this).val()?$("#at-states").show():$("#at-states").hide()});
$("#country").on("change",function(){"BE"===$(this).val()?$("#be-provinces").show():$("#be-provinces").hide()});
$("#country").on("change",function(){"CH"===$(this).val()?$("#ch-regions").show():$("#ch-regions").hide()});
...
</script>
```

The issue is, it passes the last param available within the `:address_state"... So if I choose ['california', 'ca'], it will pass through ['england', 'eng'], as an example... if ENG is the last one in the order, even if its not showing.

I assume, the only way to solve this is with a function? I have done similar things in the past but i am unsure on how i would be able to show/hide or just allow the param to pass based on a function?

How can i create a function based on the selection of the `:country`?

Or are there better alternatives to accomplishing this?

**EXAMPLE OF ISSUE:**

I choose US, then US states selection appears, I choose "CA", but what goes through is the first selection available within the "at_states" even though it is hidden.  The reason that goes through is that it's the last selection available on the form.

Comment: It will be better to post the rendered html not `<%= ...`  And if you can.. create a simple demo/snippet

Comment: Well, the issue is the params that get passed through.  The forms appears how i want.  Is there a way to demo the params that get passed?